# setReadOnly and SetDisabled not working Ext JS 7.0.0

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs7

I have a window with a form in it and pops up on click of an item in the grid. Inside the window, there is an edit button that would make the fields to `setReadOnly(false)`. Here is the button:

```
onEdit: function () {

    this.moviePopupWindow = Ext.create('MovieRental.view.MovieDetailsPopUpView');
    this.movieForm = this.moviePopupWindow.down('#movieForm');
    var saveButton = this.movieForm.down('[itemId="saveBtn"]');
    var selected = localStorage.getItem('formValues');


    this.movieForm.down('[name="Title"]').setReadOnly(false);
    this.movieForm.down('[name="Genre"]').setReadOnly(false);
    this.movieForm.down('[name="Description"]').setReadOnly(false);
    this.movieForm.down('[name="Status"]').setReadOnly(false);
    this.movieForm.down('[name="Price"]').setReadOnly(false);

    this.moviePopupWindow.updateLayout();
    saveButton.setDisabled(false);
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('formValues'));
},
```

However, the fields is still in readonly even though the button is pressed.
I tried showing the window again and although it is editable, the values of the form is gone (the form is pre-filled with the data from the grid). And the previous form is still showing.

Here are the things I tried:

~ `.updateLayout()` - not working. no error in console.
~ I tried to close the previous window and open a new one but no luck. For some reason, the `.close()` is not working. `.destroy()` is also not working.

I know its a sounds simple, but I'm really stuck here. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you create a Sencha Fiddle to demonstrate your issue?